# One thread switching between two tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have two threads communicating with each other. When one thread works second is blocked and vice versa. Is it possible to have done everything on one thread without changing the application's logic?

Example:
Robot (thread 1) is communicating with the simulator of the environment for robots (thread 2).
The robot chooses an action to take and then his thread is interrupted and the environment's thread is waked up. The environment simulator modifies the robot's environment based on the action the robot has taken. It sends back to the robot (potentially partial) information what the environment looks like. Robots thread awakens and environment thread is blocked until the robot takes the next action.

Both Robot and the environment simulator have complicated logic consisting of their own call stack.

Robot's program can call method `environment.Act(action)` from various places in various methods. The environment's simulator can call `ReadAction()` and `SendResponse` also from various places.

Since the two threads never run simultaneously is it possible to somehow use asynchronous programming or something in c# to keep everything in one thread?

I want both the robot and its environment to be callers of communication methods. I don't want to invert the logic to make them callees.

Here is what I tried:

```
class Robot
{
    public async Task RunAsync(RobotsEnvironment environment)
    {
        Belief estimatedStateRepresentation = new Belief();
        while (true)
        {
            RobotsAction action = estimatedStateRepresentation.BestAction();
            Observation observation = await environment.Act(action);
            Console.WriteLine("Robot      : " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            estimatedStateRepresentation = estimatedStateRepresentation.Update(action, observation);
        }
    }
}

class RobotsEnvironment
{
    MyConcurrentQueue<RobotsAction> actions = new MyConcurrentQueue<RobotsAction>();
    MyConcurrentQueue<Observation> observations = new MyConcurrentQueue<Observation>();
    public Task<Observation> Act(RobotsAction action)
    {
        actions.Post(action);
        return observations.ReceiveAsync();
    }

    public async Task RunAsync(State initialState)
    {
        State state = initialState;
        while (true)
        {
            RobotsAction action = await actions.ReceiveAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Environment: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            state = state.Update(action);
            observations.Post(state.GenerateObservation());
        }
    }
}
```

Since the robot never runs simultaneously with its environment. I hoped that the ManagedThreadId written in the output will be constant. Unfortunately. It seems that both robot and it's environment have their own threads and that they sometimes move to other threads.

I suspect that it may be caused by the way I implemented synchronization:

```
internal class MyConcurrentQueue<T>
{
    readonly object lockObject = new object();
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();

    public MyConcurrentQueue()
    {
        this.semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
    }

    public async Task<T> ReceiveAsync()
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (queue.Count == 0 && receivingFinished)
                throw new TaskCanceledException();
            return queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
    public void Post(T item)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(item);
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do it better to keep everything in one thread?

What is my motivation? I would just have better feeling it it would be in one thread. Does it have some advantages? I do not need it for any purpose. Shoud I even care about it? Should I somehow try to minimize the synchronization overhead?

EDIT:

This is the way how I start the threads:

```
Task.WaitAll(agent.RunAsync(environment), environment.RunAsync(initialState));
```

Comment: You're not setting the maxCount in your Semaphore slim. I think it defaults to the max
Change it to new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1) and see if that makes a difference

Comment: You are right that I will never need more than one item in the queue. But no thread tries to place there the second item anyway. They are blocked sooner. I cannot think of a way how to take advantage of setting maxCount.

Comment: How you bring the work of these two threads into one thread depends on how you got things running in those two threads in the first place, and you haven't shown that. You can't see the siding of the house from the living room.

Comment: I call the agent's and environment's code a thread even though I do not start them as threads. I run them as tasks. I edited the question and added to the bottom the line which starts both tasks.